# How to load specific rows 100 at a time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to search every 100 record so the first bulk will be 1 to 100 second will be 101 to 200 etc.
I am also using joins to combine two tables.
When I execute the query I get error saying: `The column 'ID' was specified multiple times for 'cte'.`

This is my query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY TableOne.Name
          ) AS ROW
        , *
    FROM
      DatabaseNameOne
      FULL JOIN DatabaseNameOne
      ON DatabaseNameTwo.ID= DatabaseNameOne.ID
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE,DatabaseNameOne.dateone) BETWEEN '2013-12-01' AND '2014-05-20'
)

SELECT
    *
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    ROW BETWEEN '1' AND '100'
```

Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong here?

I am using server 2008. I can select 1 to 100 record with out join, but soon as I join a table I get this error

Comment: What is your interpretation of the error message?

Comment: Aside from causing errors like this, [there are a number of other reasons not to use SELECT *](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Comment: @DanBracuk what do you mean?

Comment: I meant that the error message is pretty specific.  Did you read it or simply notice that you had one?

Comment: "DatabaseNameOne
FULL JOIN DatabaseNameOne" -> Should probably be "Two" somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume you meant to join to DatabaseNameTwo and that each table has three fields. 
What your current cte is doing if you expand the select *:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY TableOne.Name
          ) AS ROW
        , DatabaseNameOne.id,  DatabaseNameOne.SomeOtherField,  DatabaseNameOne.YetAnotherField, 
         DatabaseNameTwo.id, DatabaseNameTwo.AnotherField,  DatabaseNameTwo.HowManyMoreFieldsAreThere
   FROM
      DatabaseNameOne
      FULL JOIN DatabaseNameOne
      ON DatabaseNameTwo.ID= DatabaseNameOne.ID
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE,DatabaseNameOne.dateone) BETWEEN '2013-12-01' AND '2014-05-20'
)
```

As you can see there are two columns with teh name ID. That is what si scauseing teh error.

Since both IDs are the same, you only need to list one (one of the many reasons why you should never use select * is the repetition of data that is wasteful of precious database and network resources when you have joins). So this should work (After you  change to the real column names and table names and fix the select * in the final query which I was too lazy to do):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY TableOne.Name
          ) AS ROW
        , DatabaseNameOne.id,  DatabaseNameOne.SomeOtherField,  DatabaseNameOne.YetAnotherField, 
         DatabaseNameTwo.AnotherField,  DatabaseNameTwo.HowManyMoreFieldsAreThere
   FROM
      DatabaseNameOne
      FULL JOIN DatabaseNameOne
      ON DatabaseNameTwo.ID= DatabaseNameOne.ID
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE,DatabaseNameOne.dateone) BETWEEN '2013-12-01' AND '2014-05-20'
)

SELECT
    <List the fies here)
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    ROW BETWEEN '1' AND '100'
```

Answer (score 3):

This is your cte:

```
WITH cte AS (
       SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TableOne.Name) AS ROW,
              *
       FROM DatabaseNameOne FULL JOIN
            DatabaseNameOne
            ON DatabaseNameTwo.ID = DatabaseNameOne .ID
       WHERE convert(date, DatabaseNameOne.dateone) between '2013-12-01' and '2014-05-20'
     )
```

You are joining a table to itself and using `*` -- all the columns are duplicated.  Even if the tables are different, the `join` is on an `ID` field, so that column will be duplicated.  A CTE/subquery/table cannot have duplicate names?  How would SQL Server know which column you are referring to in a reference?

Instead, you need to list the specific columns you want from the `join`.

Comment: I think the "same table" bit may just be an anonymization glitch, given that they then use a `DatabaseNameTwo` alias in the `ON` clause.

Comment: I get error Incorrect syntax near ')'. plus where do I specify the number of records? Uswing other people suggestioins I have tried adding column names, I get same error

Comment: This is just the cte, not the full query.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Row is an integer and you trying it as varchar()

try like this

```
    WITH cte AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TableOne.Name
) 
    AS ROW,* 
FROM DatabaseNameOne JOIN DatabaseNameOne ON DatabaseNameTwo .ID= DatabaseNameOne .ID

WHERE convert(date,DatabaseNameOne .dateone) between '2013-12-01' and '2014-05-20')

SELECT * FROM cte WHERE ROW BETWEEN 1 AND 100 --not '1' and '100'
```

Comment: Although it is bad form to put integer constants in single quotes, SQL Server will convert strings to integers in an integer context.

Comment: I get same error message `The column 'ID' was specified multiple times for 'cte'.`

Comment: @User911: as said below specify column names instead of `*` then `SELECT * FROM cte WHERE ROW BETWEEN 1 AND 100`

Comment: @861051069712110711711710997114 thats what i did `select TableOne.Name from cte where ....`

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to imagine what is TableOne? Is it schema name? If it's table or acronym you may add it after table real name. Next is that we have no definitions of DatabaseNameTwo, but it's present on join condition.

Even if it's typos and cte uses correct table names inside your real script, there is no way to use the same column names from both joined tables. As far as I understand, both tables contain ID columns, it's unacceptable to use SELECT * there. Maybe using DatabaseNameOne.* or DatabaseNameTwo.* may help?

But even there it's better to determine exact column names, that your query uses, just to minimize memory usage, i/o activity and so on.